# How would I load custom CSS over an existing webpage with window.open()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-injection

I would like to load custom CSS for any web page without "touching" the original code (that is, don't scrape and re-serve content manually).  The idea is to replicate something similar to how the Stylish plugin works for Google Chrome, allowing me to replace CSS any way I need.

I was looking at the window.open function but I didn't see any way of inserting custom CSS that way, and I'm at a loss of what to try next.  Everything I've seen so far deals with 'scraping' the html of the target page but for lack of a better term, I want to avoid 'touching' the content of the page outside of CSS.  If it's possible.

The project I'm working on is for internal use and so semantics, user expectations, and so on are already being well-controlled, so "violating" any conventions or unofficial rules of web development is not an explicit concern for me at this time.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to inject a custom style sheet after `window.open`? It'd require injecting a `<link>` element and probably only works for same-origin documents.

Comment: Either that, or injecting <style> tags.  I had just thought of trying to open the window with a local html that has CSS, and an <iframe> that loads the specific document.  Would that be possible as well, to circumvent CORS?  Oddly enough, disabling web security is not an option because the browser we use may access external sites, and it seems disabling web-security applies to all instances of the browser, not just selected windows.

Comment: No. CORS says `file://` urls get a unique origin for each document (so they can't even talk amongst themselves or use features that require a CORS-enabled environment).

Comment: You mentioned this is a corporate environment/internal use. Maybe your goal can be accomplished by changing the browser's user agent stylesheet (the one that tells it how unstyled elements should look). Also, possibly see http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: @Ouroborus I thoguht that was the case, regarding CORS.  As for changing the user agent stylesheet, that won't work.  In fact, with the exception of using Chrome's App Mode via a shortcut, anything I do must be within the confines of my HTML, CSS, and JS documents.  And as of right now, it's all a "local" document, accessed via a network folder (versus hosting on a local machine, which I do not have clearance for).